# How to assign a tag value for a specific index from XML layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Well for some reason I want to assign tag value for specific index(key) from the xml layout.

```
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:tag="someTextPutFor someIndex" //how to assign this value for specific key
/>
```

So I can simply retrieve that value using

```
 someView.getTag(someIndex);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp">
<tag android:id="SomeId" android:value="SomeValue" />
</View>
```